# Setting InputAccessoryView into UISearchController

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, uisearchcontroller, inputaccessoryview

I'm currently trying to extend my Xamarin.Forms app with search bars in the navigation bar by this guide: https://codetraveler.io/2019/10/05/adding-a-search-bar-to-xamarin-forms-navigationpage/

So far it works great. But now I also want to add custom action to the keyboard based on what is available on this page. But it seems like the InputAccessoryView has no available setter for the UISearchController. So how can I set those custom actions and a Done button to it? Is there some other way to add this? Or is it maybe a bug by Xamarin that the InputAccessoryView is not setable?

Answer (score 0):

nvm sometimes a bit of sleep helps a lot. The InputAccessoryView needs to be set on the SearchBar within the UISearchController of course and not directly on the UISearchController...